# Overflow when wanting to replace a widget by a bigger widget

Tags: flutter, dart, state

Basically, I want the "setState()" method to replace the "SimpleCard" widget (A Container), by "ComplexCard" widget (also a Container) and I want the "ComplexCard" to appear in front of the other widgets.

Also, Padding is the reason why I have the overflowError, without Padding, the 2 Elevated Button would draw in the returned Container from the "build" function

```
class PieceCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Piece piece;
  PieceCard(this.piece);

  @override
  State<PieceCard> createState() => PieceCardState();
}

class PieceCardState extends State<PieceCard> {
  late Widget current;

  @override
  void initState() {
    current = SimpleCard();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          current = ComplexCard();
        });
      },
      child: current,
    );

    
  }
}

class SimpleCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleCard({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
      width: 10,
      height: 40,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            // Future will be an image
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text('Level',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    fontSize: 36.0,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 218, 107)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ComplexCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ComplexCard({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
  
  int flex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
        width: 10,
        height: 40,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: [
                  Container( // Future will be an image
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text('Level',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown,fontSize: 36.0,decoration: TextDecoration.none,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 218, 107)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50)),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (() => swapCard()),
                child: Text('SWAP', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white)),
                )
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('INFO', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white)),
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, here, the 2 Containers that contains an ElevatedButton are drawed in the Container that is returned by the build function, I would like that this Container expands to display the 2 Elevated buttons BELOW the Container that has a Stack widget as one of its grandchild

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size on `ComplexCard`. This is causing overflow issue. you can remove this

```dart
class ComplexCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ComplexCard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  int flex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
      // width: 10, //<----this and 
      // height: 40,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
```

Comment: It works but it still puts me the 2 Elevated Buttons in the Container from the build func
I would like the 2 Buttons to be below the Container and not in the Container !